# Mathbuntu flavor installation

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded the installation script from mathbuntu.org. I ran it, and it completed, but did not install anything. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. No error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the folder at /usr/share/applications folder to see if your application was installed.

Also check /var/log/apt/history.log to see what it says and post here so we can have more information because right now i can't really see what happened...